Recalculate Edges without Changing Node Positions
I have used MSAGL library in my VB.net Forms application.
I have created sample graph
Private Sub TestGraph2()
graph = New Graph()
    Dim gameNode As New Node("Game")
    Dim playerNode1 As New Node("Player 1")

    For k As Integer = 0 To 12
        graph.AddNode(k.ToString + ".ToStr")
        k += 1
    Next

    graph.AddEdge("1.ToStr", "2.ToStr")
    graph.AddEdge("3.ToStr", "2.ToStr")
    graph.AddEdge("7.ToStr", "3.ToStr")
    graph.AddEdge("8.ToStr", "2.ToStr").LabelText = "8 to 2"
    graph.AddEdge("9.ToStr", "2.ToStr")
    graph.AddEdge("10.ToStr", "9.ToStr")
    graph.AddEdge("11.ToStr", "12.ToStr").LabelText = "11 to 12"
    graph.AddEdge("1.ToStr", "11.ToStr")
    graph.AddEdge("3.ToStr", "11.ToStr").LabelText = "3 to 11"
    graph.AddEdge("2.ToStr", "4.ToStr")
    graph.AddEdge("2.ToStr", "3.ToStr").Attr.AddStyle(Style.Dotted)
    graph.AddEdge("2.ToStr", "9.ToStr", EdgeStyle.Etched)
    graph.AddEdge("9.ToStr", "5.ToStr", EdgeStyle.Bump)


    graph.CreateGeometryGraph()
    For Each node As Node In graph.Nodes
        node.Attr.Color = Microsoft.Msagl.Drawing.Color.Chocolate
        node.GeometryNode.BoundaryCurve = CreateLabelAndBoundary(node)
    Next

    For Each edge In graph.Edges
        edge.Attr.AddStyle(Style.Bold)
        If edge.Label IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim geomEdge = edge.GeometryEdge
            Dim width, height As Double
            StringMeasure.MeasureWithFont(edge.LabelText, New Font(edge.Label.FontName, CSng(edge.Label.FontSize)), width, height)
            Dim geomLabel As New Microsoft.Msagl.Core.Layout.Label(width, height, geomEdge)
            edge.Label.GeometryLabel = geomLabel
        End If
    Next
    geomGraph = graph.GeometryGraph

    Dim geomGraphComponents = Microsoft.Msagl.Core.Layout.GraphConnectedComponents.CreateComponents(geomGraph.Nodes, geomGraph.Edges)
    Dim settings1 As New SugiyamaLayoutSettings()
    settings1.LayerSeparation = 100
    settings1.EdgeRoutingSettings.EdgeRoutingMode = EdgeRoutingMode.SugiyamaSplines


    For Each subgraph In geomGraphComponents
        Dim layout As New LayeredLayout(subgraph, settings1)
        subgraph.Margins = settings1.NodeSeparation / 2
        layout.Run()
    Next

    Microsoft.Msagl.Layout.MDS.MdsGraphLayout.PackGraphs(geomGraphComponents, settings1)


    geomGraph.UpdateBoundingBox()

    '' Curve edges using SplineRouter
    'Dim router As New SplineRouter(geomGraph, 1, 1, 1) ' The parameters control padding and curvature
    'router.Run()

    ApplySplineRouting(geomGraph)

    viewer.NeedToCalculateLayout = False
    viewer.Graph = graph

End Sub

This works fine, but whenever I move node the edges overlap, I tried embedded re-layout but it also repositions the nodes as it calculates the whole graph,
So how can I recalculate edges without moving nodes, I tried searching for documentation but couldn't find any useful search.
I tried


Private Sub ApplySplineRouting(ByVal geomGraph As Microsoft.Msagl.Core.Layout.GeometryGraph)
Dim router As New SplineRouter(geomGraph, 10, 1, 1) 

router.Run()
viewer.Refresh()
End Sub

and also one of the solution from Stackoverflow
Dim shapes As IEnumerable(Of Msagl.Routing.Shape) = graphoo.GeometryGraph.Nodes.Select(Function(n) New Msagl.Routing.Shape(n.BoundaryCurve))

    ' Create the RectilinearEdgeRouter with the correct input
    Dim rectRouter As New RectilinearEdgeRouter(shapes, 10, 0, True)

    ' Run the rectilinear router to route the edges
    rectRouter.Run()

But didn't work.
